# ZipArchive.CreateEntryFromFile does not show new entry

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

I'm experiencing a strange issue here and not quite sure what I'm missing. I ran the code below and it did create a .zip file and I watched the size increase from 0KB to 8,992KB. However, as I open the .zip file, I don't see any file. And if I try to "Extract All..." from explorer, it shows "Windows can not complete the extraction" because the .zip file "is invalid". Any idea what I did wrong?

```
if (File.Exists(ZipName))
    File.Delete(ZipName);

using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.Open(ZipName, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
{
    foreach (string sFileName in FileNames)
    {
        archive.CreateEntryFromFile(sFileName,sFileName,CompressionLevel.Optimal);
    }
}
```

Comment: is this with Ionic.Zip, or system.io.compression? or something else?

Comment: This is System.IO.Compression

Comment: Your code looks pretty much identical to the MSDN documentation, have you tried opening the zip file with some other tool such as 7zip to see if it also has issues with it?

Comment: Yes. I follow this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive.aspx. No, I have not tried open it with other zip/unzip tools. I will find some to try

Comment: It's working on my machine

Comment: @CodingGorilla: I extracted with WinRAR and it shows the files. Any idea why MS Windows Explorer couldn't recognize it? I want to keep it simple for the customers so they don't have to install WinRAR.

Comment: @SamIam: the XML file is almost a gig (831MB)

Comment: Not really sure, maybe try changing from `CompressionLevel.Optimal` to a `CompressionLevel.Fastest`?  Maybe the optimal level uses a newer algorithm that windows doesn't recognize? (I'm totally guessing)

Comment: I tried CompressionLevel.Fastest and Windows Explorer still doesn't show the entry nor extract the file

Comment: It appears the full path of the entry in the archive is too long. After I change the value of the 2nd parameter (sFileName) to just the file name, explorer shows the entry and able to extract it as well

Answer (score 1):

You need to strip the drive letter from the entryName, which is the 3rd parameter to CreateEntryFromFile().

So instead of

```
archive.CreateEntryFromFile(sFileName, sFileName, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
```

Use

```
archive.CreateEntryFromFile(sFileName, sFileName.Substring(3), CompressionLevel.Optimal);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, and I discovered a solution.  It turns out that I was feeding the method a full path to the file for both filename arguments, like so:

```
// This gets a list of files with their full paths
var fileList = Directory.GetFiles(_outputDir, "*.txt");

foreach (var file in fileList)
{
    archive.CreateEntryFromFile(file, file, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
}
```

That gave me the same problem you had -- an empty zip file, which was invalid.  (By the say, my file paths weren't that long -- they were `C:\Results\[some_guid].txt`.)

The solution was to get the files as FileInfo objects, then for the first argument use the full path and for the second argument just use the file name, like so:

```
// This gets a set of FileInfo objects, with a FullName property that is
// the full path to the file, and a Name property that is just the file name.
var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(_outputDir);
var fileList = directoryInfo.GetFiles("*.txt");

foreach (var file in fileList)
{
    archive.CreateEntryFromFile(file.FullName, file.Name, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
}
```

This ended up working perfectly.  If I opened the zip file, the files were there.  If I extracted it, the extraction worked and the files seemed to be valid.